# How to change textbox size and location dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I have a datagridview on a form and the visibility and width of columns is changing dynamically. Also, some textboxes to add values to each column. Is there any way to change the textbox location and width according to the datagrid column size and location?

For example, if I need to hide the "Selling" column, the textbox above the selling column should also go invisible. The "SIH" column will come next to the "Cost" column and text boxes need to move accordinately

[image: form like this]

Comment: are the textboxes in a layout panel? or distributed freely on the form?

Comment: Not on a layout panel. just on the form

Comment: do you have the textboxes organized in any manner ?=! in a collection for example ?

Comment: No. currently just placed above the datagridview

Comment: The point of DataGridView is that the user can type values directly in the grid, no textboxes required.  Set its AllowUserToAddRows property to true.

Comment: "Also, some textboxes to add values to each column." you cannot really add values to only certain columns, it is a row based structure. Or am I missing something. Hans Passant has stressed a very important point. Please post the code that shows how you feed in the data into the DataGridView

Comment: If you know what you want it will be possible; there are enough dgv-events to adapt yopur tbs to the changing dgv layout..

Comment: Avoid this headache and just enable `AllowUserToAddRows` as mentioned. See [Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN) to create a DateTimePicker column.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I am doing the changes to AllowUserToAddRows